# Find Missing Values from sql table

Tags: php, sql

I have an sql table as below

```
+---+-------+   
|Sl | Name  |   
+---+-------+   
| 1 | Name1 |    
| 2 | Name2 |    
| 3 | Name3 |      
| 4 | Name4 |    
| 5 | Name5 |   
+---+-------+
```

I have a php array with values (Name1, Name4)

The query result should return the Name values along with their corresponding Sl values which are not present in the array.
like

RESULT

```
+---+-------+   
|Sl | Name  |   
+---+-------+       
| 2 | Name2 |    
| 3 | Name3 |          
| 5 | Name5 |   
+---+-------+
```

How can i make this possible? Thanks in advance

blasteralfred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct a query using `not in` -

```
select * from table where name not in ('Name1','Name4')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name NOT IN (Name1,Name4)
```